# Why Superfetch is enabled after restarting computer?

Tags: windows-8.1, services, windows-services, superfetch

I had disabled the `Superfetch` from `services.msc` but it was enabled by itself after restarting the computer. I don't want to use it. How do I disable it completely?

Comment: Did you stop it or disabled it ?

Comment: @Alex I did both of them.

Comment: Try to disable prefetch too. Here is [link](https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/disable-superfetch-prefetch-windows-8/) how to do that

Comment: why do you want to disable this useful feature? For a SSD, windows 8 already detects that it is a SSD and doesn't preftech data from it

Comment: @magicandre1981 I don't have SSD, the superfetch slows my computer down by causing disk usage 100% and it is the reason of heating my disk up.

Comment: without superfetch the PC would be even **more** slow. Replace the slow HDD with a SSD and you never have any issues again.

Comment: @magicandre1981 As I observe there is no need to buy it for now because after disabling superfetch solves the problems I mentioned.

Comment: @Alex I did what you said by following that link you shared but the problem, unfortunately, continues..